# ARP and layer flooding

Tags: ip-address, mac-address, arp

it is my understanding that nodes are not aware of the mac address of other nodes they want to communicate with, when a frame is created to communicate node A with node B, the destination mac address field would be empty, to avoid that, ARP comes into play, Ethernet can "peek" into the ip packet in the payload to look at the IP address of node B and ask "who has this IP address" as a broadcast in the LAN, if node B is in the lan, it will be reply and the mac address will then be know as well as the interface to which node B is connected (Mac address and ARP tables updated).  If there is no response, the frame will be addressed to the mac address of the gateway to start its journey to the final destination in another network.
When re-reading the CCNA book, it indicates that unknow unicasts are flooded to all interfaces and when one replies then the switch knows the interface to which that mac address is connected, which makes sense if I know the mac address of a destination and the entry is not yet in the mac address table of the switch.
While I understand that "flooding" process, it conflicts with the statement that nodes know the IP address of other nodes but not their mac address.  Are there circumstances in which nodes know mac addresses of other nodes or is ARP always needed to gather that info inthe ARP table?

Comment: Definitely off-topic as it's not a programming question. It can possibly be welcome (after a bit of formating please) in [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).